# Vue keep-alive not working in Quasar, mounted hook is always called using $router.back()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a Quasar app where I would like to cache certain pages using keep-alive for the following scenario:
User navigates from home page to Page 1, then from Page 1 user navigates to Page 2, then user goes back using $router.back() to Page 1 from Page 2, in current scenario the mounted() hook is ran again in Page 1 and the page re-rendered making another API call which is not necessary at all.
My current implementation looks like this:

```
  <q-page-container class="overflow-auto">
    <keep-alive>
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    </keep-alive>
  </q-page-container>
```

I have setup the name property in the routes and also in the page itself. I also tried using
`include="Home,Workout`"
but the result is same, the mounted hook runs each time and the page is re-rendered. I also need the page to stay alive so I can change the scroll behavior, scroll back to where the user was before he left Page 1. That is remembered I can see the console log for example showing `y:883` but since the page is re-rendered it ends up at the top again.
Worth to mention maybe that I am using router hash mode?

Comment: Since you are using `$route.fullPath` as the key, make sure you are accessing the Page with the exact same path, including the query and the hash. Alternatively you can use route name as the key.

Comment: @Owl But will using route name also work when I have a different query prop? I will have to make a dynamic key I guess which is a combination of the name + props to make it re-render for prop change for example '/workout/1' and 'workout/2'

Comment: No, if you are using route name as the key and the parameter changed it won't re render. You can create dynamic key for each route depending on your needs, or alternatively you can use name as the key and put a `$route` watcher on your component

Answer (score 6):

`router-view` can no longer be used directly inside `keep-alive`. Use slot props instead:

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive>
        <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
</router-view>
```